# remove matrix from a list of matrices

Tags: r

I have a list of 12 matrices called `M` and I'm trying to remove every matrix from the list that has 0 rows.

I know that I can manually remove those matrices with (for example, to remove the second matrix) `M[2] <- NULL`.  I would like to use logic to remove them with something like: `M <- M[nrow(M)>0,]` (but that obviously didn't work).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another option that could work is `Filter` in `base R`

```
Filter(nrow, M)
```

It works because 0 is considered as FALSE and all other values as TRUE

If there are also some attributes, `gv` from `collapse` could maintain it

```
library(collapse)
gv(M, function(x) nrow(x) > 0)
```

Comment: super elegant `Filter` approach! +1!

Answer (score 5):

Use `sapply()` to get a logical vector of non-zero matrices, then use that vector to select/subset:

```r
nzm <- sapply(M, function(m) nrow(m)>0)
M <- M[nzm]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a one-liner.

```
M <- M[sapply(M, nrow) != 0]
```

---

#### Data creation code

```
M <- lapply(1:5, function(n){
  if(n %% 2 == 0)
    matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 2)
  else
    matrix(1:4, nrow = 2)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I think @Akrun has the cleanest answer. I made this up before I saw his.  It is reproducible and also explains a different way of going about it that I used with out thinking about more elegant solutions.

```
# create list of matrices
matrixlist <- list(matrix(nrow=4,ncol=4,1),
     matrix(nrow=4,ncol=4,1),
     matrix(nrow=0,ncol=4,1),
     matrix(nrow=4,ncol=4,1))
matrixlist

# Identify matrices in my list that have at least one row
idx <- lapply(lapply(matrixlist, `[`), nrow) > 0

# subset the original list with this criteria
my_revised_matrixlist <- matrixlist[idx]

my_revised_matrixlist
```

All this was accomplished by Akrun's simple `Filter(nrow, matrixlist)`

Answer (score 0):

Another option worth mentioning with `purrr` is `keep()`, `discard()`, or `compact()`. The package `purrr` is my go-to these days with lists.

```r
library(purrr)

# simplest by far
compact(M)

# probably a bit easier to remember what you did later
keep(M, ~ nrow(.) > 0)
discard(M, ~ nrow(.) == 0)
```